# Is it possible to reset the iOS device settings of an app to default?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am curious if I could reset the iOS settings e.g. location/pictures to default, so the user gets asked everytime if he wants to allow the location or camera usage.

At the moment I am trying to do this with Ionic/Cordova.

Maybe anyone of you guys knows how to do that or can tell me if that is even possible.

Comment: It is not possible. Once the user has been promoted and answered your app cannot ask again. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Once the user allows usage the app can't ask again.